# Pandas find next change above/below a certain threshold from a time series

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a timeseries I want to calculate for every row whether the next change is above or below a certain threshold for example 2 and -2 respectively, giving a value of +1 for a positive move or -1 for a negative move

For example:

```
Col1  Diff > 2 or <-2
1     1 - 3-1 gives a positive value
2     1 - 4-2 gives a positive value
3     1 - 5-3 give a positive value
4    -1 - 2-4 give a negative value even though the next change is up
5    -1 - 3-5 negative
4    -1 - 2-4 negative
3   
2
```

This is really just a twist on the idea of 'range' bars, but calculated at each value instead of next value.

The only way i can think of at the moment is to iterate through the next values summing the difference until the sum of differences == the threshold value in this case 2.

This is my best effort:

```
for i in range(0, len(df2.a)-1):
    if (i < len(df.a)-1):
        y= i + 1
        while ((np.abs(df.a[y]- df.a[i]) <= 0.015) & (y < len(df.a)-1)):
            y = y + 1
        if df[a][y] - df[a][i] >= 0.015:
            df['dir_y'][i] = 1
            #print(1)
        else:
            df['dir_y'][i] = -1
            #print(-1)
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand how you arrive at the diff column as an output, are you just performing a cumsum on the differences and then indicating the direction of change?

Comment: best explained by example: for 1, the next value is 2 then 3 so 3-1 = 2 hence +1 value in diff column, for 4 on the other the positive change is only 5-4 =1 so the the next change is negative since 2-4 = 2 so -1 is the value

Comment: Can you explain why 4 is treated differently here

Comment: so for 4 the value change to 5 but since 5-4 =1 is not >= 2 it does not lead to a positive value. iterating further we arrive at 4 ( no change) 3 ( change of -1) and 2 (change of -2 <= -2) therefore diff = -1 for a negative change.

Comment: It appears that you are comparing the elements two indices apart.  The values in the fourth and sixth rows are both 4, so why isn't the "diff" 0 for the fourth row?

Comment: sorry, i didnt mean you have to compare values two rows apart i meant you have to iterate through the next rows till you find a change that is above or below 2/-2

Comment: Ah, I see.  So for the fourth row, you have to look at the next *four* rows to figure out the change; that's why the comment says `2 - 4`.

Comment: exactly, i was having trouble explaining it I would use a for loop and a while loop inside the for loop if i was using an array. Where the while loop checks if the difference of current value against the next values

Comment: How long will the sequence typically be?  There is a vectorized approach, but it involves the outer difference, which means both the time and memory complexity would be O(n**2), where n is the length of the series.

Comment: the series will be very large 10,000+ its trade data! also i updated the qu with a method i think would work not checked it though.